# interaction failed - discord.js 14.0.9

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to create a bot in discord.js ( 14.0.11 ) for a system of recommendations, which will then be accepted via button. The problem is that when I press the button, it says interaction failed. I have tried these 3 troubleshooting methods, but none fix. I would like it to just send the default message when the button is pressed. https://pastebin.com/h23PyzyQ this is the full index code

Version 1:

```
`        if (interaction.customId == "idBottone1") {
        const embed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor('#ffef00')
        .setTitle("Consiglio accettato")
        .setDescription(interaction.user.tag + " è un Dio sceso in terra, ottima idea amico!")
        .addFields(
        { name: 'Modifica consigliata', value: `${msg}` },
        { name: 'Come funziona?', value: 'I player potranno dire la loro, ma la scelta finale rimane allo staff. Ovviamente la decisione sarà basata sull\'opinione pubblica'},
        { name: 'Come mai abbiamo accettato?', value: 'Pensiamo che il consiglio possa portare a miglioramenti nel server, quindi lo troviamo utile!'}
      )
        .setFooter({
          text: `Grazie del Consiglio!`
      })
      interaction.deferUpdate();
      interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [embed2], fetchReply: true, components: [row1] })
    }`
```

Version 2:

```
        if (interaction.customId == "idBottone1") {
        const embed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor('#ffef00')
        .setTitle("Consiglio accettato")
        .setDescription(interaction.user.tag + " è un Dio sceso in terra, ottima idea amico!")
        .addFields(
        { name: 'Modifica consigliata', value: `${msg}` },
        { name: 'Come funziona?', value: 'I player potranno dire la loro, ma la scelta finale rimane allo staff. Ovviamente la decisione sarà basata sull\'opinione pubblica'},
        { name: 'Come mai abbiamo accettato?', value: 'Pensiamo che il consiglio possa portare a miglioramenti nel server, quindi lo troviamo utile!'}
      )
        .setFooter({
          text: `Grazie del Consiglio!`
      })
      interaction.deferReply();
      interaction.deferUpdate({ embeds: [embed2], fetchReply: true, components: [row1] })
    }
```

Version 3:

```
        if (interaction.customId == "idBottone1") {
        const embed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor('#ffef00')
        .setTitle("Consiglio accettato")
        .setDescription(interaction.user.tag + " è un Dio sceso in terra, ottima idea amico!")
        .addFields(
        { name: 'Modifica consigliata', value: `${msg}` },
        { name: 'Come funziona?', value: 'I player potranno dire la loro, ma la scelta finale rimane allo staff. Ovviamente la decisione sarà basata sull\'opinione pubblica'},
        { name: 'Come mai abbiamo accettato?', value: 'Pensiamo che il consiglio possa portare a miglioramenti nel server, quindi lo troviamo utile!'}
      )
        .setFooter({
          text: `Grazie del Consiglio!`
      })
      interaction.deferReply({ embeds: [embed2], fetchReply: true, components: [row1] })
    }
```

Obviously the code is cut, and if I need any other part to understand the error I'll send it right away.I tried with only channel.send but it is where the error starts.
Anyone know how to fix? ^^

Comment: You have not provided the code of row1 and the interaction handler for the button

Comment: Now i'll put it ^^

Comment: I assume the message is still replying correctly, right? Try using the ButtonInteraction `.followUp()` method instead (or `.update()` if you're able to reduce the number of messages sent by keeping it in one). Does that resolve the issue correctly?

Comment: Sorry, i really didnt get what do you mean. The message wont appear when i press on a button because of the error.